# How sample data that has to be distributed in different criteria

Tags: sql-server, distribution

I am looking for a way to sample data using 2 different criterias, is there anyone who can assist?

I have this that that I have clean with 2000 records. I would like to sample 100 clients distributed at 80% employed and 20 % self employed, furthermore on I have to apply another criteria. Each of the employed and self_employed sample will have to be further distributed by profession, 20% Lawyers, 10% Doctors, 50% Engineers and 20% Accountants.

this is what the data looks like:

```
Client ID | self employed | Profession
123456    | yes           |lawyer
123457    | no            |doctor
123458    | yes           |accountant
123459    | yes           |accountant
123460    | yes           |engineer
123461    | yes           |lawyer
123462    | no            |engineer
123456    | yes           |doctor
123456    | yes           |lawyer
123456    | yes           |engineer
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't help with the SQL, but the basic idea is straightforward.  You need to cross the categories of employment by the professions, with the desired percentages in the margins.  Then fill out the table by multiplying the row and column percentages:

```
              employed | unemployed
              -------- | ----------- 
     Lawyer |      16% |         4% | 20%
     Doctor |       8% |         2% | 10%
   Engineer |      40% |        10% | 50%
 Accountant |      16% |         4% | 20%
              --------   ----------- 
                   80%          20%
```

The entries in the table are what percentage of each crossed category you want in your sample.  Since you want a total sample size of 100, multiply each percentage by 100 to get the desired sample size.  Given your stated proportions, you want 16 employed lawyers, 4 unemployed lawyers, 8 employed doctors, etc.

Divide your data into subsets corresponding to the 8 categories, and randomly select the appropriate number from each subset.  I don't know if SQL provides a random shuffling capability, but if so that's an easy way to select the sample without replacement.  Shuffle the employed lawyers and take the first 16, shuffle the unemployed lawyers and take the first 4, and so on.  Note that this presumes that each category has enough elements to supply the desired size sample.